# Playing a single file onPress react native and expo av

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo-av

I have a json that looks like this

```
{
    q: 'Sitting crossed legged',
    a: 'Anza',
    url: 'assets/audio/Anza.mp3'
},
{
    q: 'Attention!',
    a: 'Kiotsuke!',
    url: 'assets/audio/Kiotzuke.mp3'
},
{
    q: 'Bow!',
    a: 'Rei!',
    url: 'assets/audio/Rei.mp3'
},
```

And my component using expo av looks like this

```
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import ScreenTitle from '../../components/ScreenTitle';
import yellowbelt from '../../components/vocab/yellowbelt';
import {Audio} from 'expo-av';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';


const RokkyuRoute = () => {  
  const [sound, setSound] = useState();

  const playSound = async (audioPath) => {
    console.clear();
    console.log('Playing Sound: ', FileSystem.documentDirectory + audioPath);
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      { uri: FileSystem.documentDirectory + audioPath },
      { shouldPlay: true }
    );
    setSound(sound);
  };

  console.log('Playing Sound: ', sound);

  useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

  return(
    <View style={{flex:1, height:"100%"}}>
      <View style={styles.yellowscreentitle}>
        <ScreenTitle title="Yellow Belt - Rokkyu" style={styles.darkh1}/>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.routecontainer}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View>
            {yellowbelt.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <View key={index} style={styles.item}>
                  <View style={styles.question}>
                    <Text style={styles.questiontext}>{index+1}. {item.q} </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.answer}>
                    <Text style={styles.answertext}>{item.a}</Text>

                    {item.url && 
                      <TouchableOpacity 
                        style={styles.button} 
                        onPress={() => playSound(item.url)}>
                        <Icon name="play" size={25} color={theme.colors.primary}/>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    }                 
                  </View>
                </View>
              )
            })}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
};

export default RokkyuRoute

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  yellowscreentitle:{
    backgroundColor: "#ffe100",
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 25,
  },
  darkh1:{
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: theme.colors.dark,
  },
  routecontainer:{
    padding:25,
    paddingBottom: 250,
  },
  item:{
    width: "100%",
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  question:{
    width: "100%",
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  answer:{
    width: "100%",
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  questiontext:{
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: theme.colors.dark,
  },
  answertext:{
    fontSize: 16,
    color: theme.colors.dark,
  },
  button:{
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.secondary,
    borderRadius: 50,
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  }
})
```

I have tried everything I can think of including replicating [**this**](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#playing-sounds) and with a single file rather than a mapped prop and I can't get it to play. I also added require in front of every instance of the file uri and nothing

EDIT - Following Ben Smith suggestions in the comments I installed FileSystem from expo-file-system and recreated the `playSound()` function. Console logging the audioPath that get's the path clicked on, and appending it to FileSystem I get this, But this is not the only sound. Each item has their own sound in the json so it must come from item.url

```
audioPath:  file:///Users/lotusms/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/79B602DF-85B4-4ABE-8745-4A3276E07C58/data/Containers/Data/Application/D0605A63-2061-4064-9B10-5304381E715F/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fjudopedia-app-d3ac072a-351a-46b3-b19f-00fec4e03363/assets/audio/Sensei.mp3
```

But still no sound

I'm out of ideas. Any helps is appreciated

Comment: you use vite? or webpack?

Comment: React Native. I assume it uses webpack. Definitely not vite

Comment: please install plugin `url-loader` https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/

Comment: Doing some research, react native doesn't use webpack either. Is there a way to do this without webpack, babel and all that mess. Webpack bundles JS, HTML, and CSS. React Native doesn't use HTML or CSS. It doesn't run on a browser

Comment: In your view your `onPress` handler calls `prepareToPlay(item.url)`. However in your component you are calling `uri: audioPath.url,`. This wont work as `audioPath` is already a URL, its a string with no `url` property.

Comment: @BenSmith I removed. url from audioPath. I don't get an error but I also don't get the sound

Comment: @LOTUSMS suspected that would be the case given that you have tried other implementations too.

Comment: I suspect you need to be more explicit with your path. You may need to pass an absolute Expo file path https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/. e.g. something like `await sound.loadAsync({ uri: Expo.FileSystem.documentDirectory + filename, shouldPlay: true })`

Comment: @BenSmith I'll edit my question to show the latest changes

Comment: @LOTUSMS so you have tried `await sound.loadAsync(require(audioPath), {shouldPlay: true,});` and it didn't work? From the reading I've done its clear that you need to use `require` to import your local audio assets.

Comment: Can you provide the entire source code? I don't know your directory tree

Comment: @TachibanaShin I replaced it with the entire component code

Comment: @LOTUSMS why not store the audio somewhere like s3 and load it from there?

Comment: @mused It's a possibility but it will still need to reference a url regardless. Unless you're saying this wont play because it doesnt recognize `file:///Users/lotusms/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/79B602DF-85B4-4ABE-8745-4A3276E07C58/data/Containers/Data/Application/D0605A63-2061-4064-9B10-5304381E715F/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fjudopedia-app-d3ac072a-351a-46b3-b19f-00fec4e03363/assets/audio/Sensei.mp3` as a real location path

Comment: @LOTUSMS I think dynamically mapping the path not working for static path it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the local audio file path, you can use it directly in the AudioPlayer component. Here's how you can modify the code:
Also, check the working snack example here

https://snack.expo.dev/qN9MBoJH5

Update the AudioPlayer component to accept a local file path:jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity ,SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

const App = () => {
  const [sound, setSound] = useState();

  const playSound = async () => {
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      { uri: "https://download.samplelib.com/mp3/sample-3s.mp3" },
      { shouldPlay: true }
    );
    setSound(sound);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={playSound}>
      <Text>Play Audio</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Make sure that the provided path is correct and points to the actual audio file on your local device. This example assumes that the file path is correct, and the audio file is accessible at that location.

Comment: Unfortuntely it doesn't work. Not hardcoding the sound file or passing item.url so that it plays the sound in the path for each item. I edited the question with the entire code

Comment: you can make it dynamic audio path is just a ref it's up to you how you want to use this one just pass your dynamic file path it will work now you can also check the snack example https://snack.expo.dev/qN9MBoJH5 for now i am using http path you can use local path

Comment: I'm aware that the snack example works, but that is an unrelated code stack. Mine doesn't even with their file running statically

Comment: I accepted your answer because it got me the closest to a solution without errors. It worked once I hosted the audio somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

This works for a single audio file if you specify the full file path.

```
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ScreenTitle from '../../components/ScreenTitle'
import yellowbelt from '../../components/vocab/yellowbelt'
import { Audio } from 'expo-av'
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'

const RokkyuRoute = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, height: '100%' }}>
      <View style={styles.yellowscreentitle}>
        <ScreenTitle title="Yellow Belt - Rokkyu" style={styles.darkh1} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.routecontainer}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View>
            {yellowbelt.map((item, index: number) => {
              return <Play key={index} index={index} item={item} />
            })}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Load each audio in its component. If you plan to store the files in the cloud you can try the commented code that should work.

```
const Play = ({ item, index }) => {
  const AudioPlayer = useRef(new Audio.Sound())

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadAudio = async () => {
      if (item.url) {
        //specify the full file path, dynamic file path not working
        await AudioPlayer.current.loadAsync(require('assets/audio/Rei.mp3'))
        //if you store the audio in the cloud try this
        //await AudioPlayer.current.loadAsync({uri: item.url})
      }
    }

    loadAudio()

    return () => {
      if (AudioPlayer.current) {
        // Stop and unload audio when the component is unmounted
        AudioPlayer?.current?.stopAsync()
        AudioPlayer?.current?.unloadAsync()
      }
    }
  }, [item])

  const playSound = async () => {
    const status = await AudioPlayer.current.getStatusAsync()

    if (status.isLoaded) {
      await AudioPlayer.current.playAsync()
    }
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <View style={styles.question}>
        <Text style={styles.questiontext}>
          {index + 1}. {item.q}{' '}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.answer}>
        <Text style={styles.answertext}>{item.a}</Text>

        {item.url && (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={playSound}>
            <Icon name="play" size={25} color={theme.colors.primary} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I'm getting 87 errors of `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 83):
Error: The Sound is already loading.`

Comment: @LOTUSMS is your audio file path correct? use relative path. I've tested it from my end it's working.

Comment: Can you provide a snack with it working? I am getting no sound and a different error this time `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -1002 and domain "NSURLErrorDomain".
Error: The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -1002 and domain "NSURLErrorDomain".`

Comment: One thing I noticed after console logging item.url or uri from your code is that it logs all of the values for item.url. Not just the one clicked on. That could be part of the problem. You are passing the entire object "item" as a prop to the Play component. But in the Play component, you are calling an annonymous function to play the Sound. That could work with one statically mounted file, but to play a file that is being clicked it needs an id or index or some form of prop identifying the object. Something is not matching